# Variable size MnSymbol ullcorner vs. lsem

Tags: delimiters, debugging, metafont, mnsymbol

Running LaTeX on the code below generates this output:

[image: mismatched delimiters]

The point is that the `\lsem` and `\rsem` brackets extend indefinitely, while `\ullcorner` and `\ulrcorner` seem to only extend for two lines.

Does anyone have any idea why? I'd be happy to debug the metafont code and try to patch it.

(the relevant file seems to be `Sym-Delim.mf`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\begin{document}
\[
\left\lsem
\begin{aligned}
1\\ 2\\ 3\\ 4\\ 5\\ 6
\end{aligned}
\right\ulrcorner
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: the corners are meant to be just that, corners. (google "quine corners", although those are only the upper ones.)  perhaps you are looking for the `\rceil` and `\rfloor` symbols.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to keep them in the corners, but I want them to extend further until they actually mark the corners of the box they're delimited, like the semantic brackets do. Currently they don't go as far as the corners of the whole box, but only extend one line above/below the baseline.

Comment: if the "corners" you want are significantly different from what's already provided (and which has been accepted into unicode), please provide a published reference that shows the different ones in use.  i am willing to submit such a request to unicode (i was the conduit to unicode for the massive addition of math symbols in unicode 4), but the committee requires solid documentation of accepted use.

Comment: Thanks for the willingness! I have no idea whether the modification I want is in a published use or not. I'm a researcher, and I am using this notation for something that's not in standard use. I want to be able to typeset the notation I am using rather than change my notation. :)

Comment: Ah, I think we were talking in cross-purpose for a bit. I think the Unicode symbol is fine. What's not working properly is the way TeX/metafont operate together to get the variable sized delimiter working. The white space inside the delimiter should stretch more so that the corners will appear in the same height as the corners of the boundary of the box it delimits.

Comment: oh, that's indeed an entirely different matter.  the design is the prerogative of the font designer, although there are indeed recognized "preferences".  i don't know anything about the origin of the `MnSymbol` fonts; the ams bases its preferences on the monotype tradition, which (in this case) is matched by what is provided by the `amsfonts` (through `amssymb.sty`).  i must refer you to the developer of the `MnSymbol` fonts, who should be identified in the manual for the package.